# I can't change the Stack Overflow for Teams avatar

Tags: support, profile-picture

When going to *Stack Overflow for Teams* I have a different avatar than my `Public Q&A` profile. But I don't know how to change the avatar for the team. This one is a computer-generated avatar.

Comment: No repro. My avatar is the same network wide across chat, se sites and teams.

Comment: Have you tried changing your SO profile picture? (i.e. here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current)

Comment: @Cai I like to have two different avatars, one for the public Q&A and one for my team.

Comment: @Rempargo afaik that’s not possible, Team profiles sync with the public SO profile. The fact that you have a different avatar now is a bug

Comment: @Cai So I should unlink both profiles to get what I want? They Team profile has another e-mail address.

Comment: @Rempargo possibly, I’m not sure if that’s possible though (maybe best to contact SE directly about that)